# mod_rewrite does not hide subdirectory

Tags: mod-rewrite

On my server I have multiple domains.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# 1. Redirect multiple domains to http://domain.de/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://domain.de/$1 [L,R,NE]

# 2. Redirect all requests to /subdirectory
RewriteRule ^$ /subdirectory [L]
```

The 2. rule is working correctly, but it is not hiding the subdirectory in the url nor does it work as intended: a request for `http://domain.de/content/image.png` returns 404, because the actual file is located in `http://domain.de/subdirectory/content/image.png`

Furthermore, I have some folders with tools located aside the subdirectory `/subdirectory`. I want to make sure I can still access them. This is currently working.

## Question

How can I make sure, that the request for `http://domain.de/content/image.png` works?

## What I tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
RewriteRule (.*) /subdirectory/$1 [L]
```

But that just returns error 500 with the following entry in the apache error log: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

## Edit

After guidance provided by Ravi Thapliyal, there is (I guess) one thing remaining: Removing the subdirectory from the url.

```
[user@domain html]$ curl -I domain.de/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 21 Oct 2013 12:42:22 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Location: http://domain.de/subdirectory/index.php
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
```

This is what gets returned, but I actually want to get the html not a location header which then of course redirects me externally to the subdirectory, which is then visible to the user. Might it have something to do with another .htaccess file from a subdirectory?

## Edit2

Seems the problem is related to the typo3 installation behind the `subdirectory`. The accepted answer works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first rule should do an external redirect (changing the domain internally won't matter at all)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://domain.de/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Your second rule is not required. The new rule would cover root `/` request as well.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1 [L]
```

The two `RewriteCond`s on `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` would make sure you can access any files `-f` or directories `-d` present outside `/subdirectory`.

---

Basically, the condition `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` prevents redirection if the URL path points to any existing directory. This prevents a URL like `/existing-directory` to be redirected to `/subdirectory/existing-directory`.

But, this could also prevent a root URL `/` request which is why you received a *directory index forbidden* error. Hence, the above condition is `[OR]`'d with `%{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$` to allow `/` to be redirected to `/subdirectory` as well.

Comment: This will result in 403 when accessing domain.de. Error log says: `Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/`

Comment: Add a `RewriteCond` for `^/$` as well.

Comment: Which leaves me with one thing remaining: The visible subdirectory in the url.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you well. Could you tell what URL you used, what you got redirected to and what you need instead?

Comment: As per my rules, accessing `/` would do an internal rewrite to `/subdirectory` (no `[R]` flag was used). Is it possible you have other rules or htaccess files as well? Can you update your full htaccess code and also try with any other htaccess files removed?

Comment: So I tested your solution on localhost and it worked as expected. Seems to me that the error is not caused by this .htaccess file but by the typo3 installation behind the `subdirectory`. What is the rule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$` doing?

Comment: Actually, that rule should match `^$` within `.htaccess`, `^/$` within `httpd.conf` or be `^/?$` to work in both. I suggest replacing it with `^/?$`. Please, take a look at my update on what this condition does.